# Adding a new field with default value in a collection in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am adding a new boolean field in a collection by adding an attribute to a Java Class entity that is being used in the MongoRepository interface. However, the existing documents' new field is being initialised as null in the database. I want the new field's default value in existing documents to be set to false. How can this be done in Spring Data MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

Let say your version 1 Java entity was

```
@Document
Public Class Person {
@Id
Private String id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
.........
.........
```

And later you have introduced

```
@Document
Public Class Person {
@Id
Private String id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Boolean isAlive; //New Boolean attribute
.........
.........
```

In java the default value of an instance object is null and so a document in mongoDB with no value for isAlive will be defaulted to null. If you need the default value to be false you could do this

```
private Boolean isAlive = Boolean.FALSE;
```

Comment: if you query the database, this wouldn't set existing documents to have isAlive=false.

Comment: What i have proposed was to set the default at the java level. To handle things at the DB level you could do one of the two things, 1. If you have queries reading this document, make them assume null as false 2. Write a script that will update all your existing documents new attribute to false if they don't already have a value set to them.